# Uniform convergence of a series of functions on a given interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence

**My problem:** To determine and prove whether the series $\sum \frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{n}}$ converges uniformly on $ [0,1)$.

**My solution:** First, I should note that despite seeing graphically that *it looks like* the series might converge uniformly on $[0,1)$, my intuition tends towards the opposite.

*Claim.* The series $\sum \frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{n}}$ does not converge uniformly on $ [0,1)$.

*Proof.* First note, that convergence of the series means convergence of the sequence of its partial sums; this means that  $\sum \frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{n}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$ if and only if so does the sequence $\displaystyle (g_n (x)) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k}}{1+x^{k}} \right) $. Additionally, $f_n$ is continuous for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $x\in [0,1)$, which implies that the limit function must also be continuous (by the Theorem 24.3). In other words, the function 
    \begin{equation}\nonumber
    \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = \sum\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} = g(x)
\end{equation}
    must be continuous on $[0,1)$. However, we know that for $x=0$ the series converges to $0$, while for $x\neq 0$  $\sum \frac{x^{n}}{1+x^{n}}>0$. (There is a theorem in our book regarding the uniform continuous limit of a function being a continuous function which is what I was trying to go into.)

In the last bit, I mean to somehow say that the series loses its $n$-dependency and therefore is not continuous. I'm not sure how to. Also, I am not sure whether it is a legitimate reason for lacking continuity.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The dependency on the dummy variable $n$ is always lost in the limit. It's like lamenting the fact that the quantity $L:=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{-n}$ is not a function of $n$: it was never meant to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the series $\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converge uniformly on $x\in [0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315845/does-the-series-sum-fracxn1xn-converge-uniformly-on-x-in-0-1)

Comment: This strategy (show the limit/sum function is not continuous) works sometimes but not here. In fact, we have uniform convergence in $[0,a]$ for any $0<a<1$, so the sum function $g$ is actually continuous in $[0,1)$. The "problems" arise when $x$ approaches $1$, not $0$.